# Passing name of button on click to controller in web2py

Tags: ajax, web2py

Basically what i want is that in my view file i have a list of various restaurants,and in front of each of them is a "show" button,which on clicking should display three more buttons(dynamically),where each button performs some action regarding the corresponding restaurant name(like show menu,show reviews)(this action should be dynamic too). Can anybody help me with this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In the view you can place a link and a target container:

```
{{=A('the link', callback=URL('controller', 'function', args=[my_arg]), target="callback-target", _class="btn btn-default")}}
<div id="callback-target"></div>
```

If the link is clicked the `function` in `controller` is called and you can read the argument `my_arg` with:

```
def function():
    data = request.args(0)
    response.flash('Data received!')
    return DIV('Return anything ...')
```

The returned data is displayed in `<div id="callback-target"></div>`